# Figure and Table next to each other in IEEEtrans with specific caption style

Tags: tables, floats, minipage, ieeetran

I'm looking for a solution where I can put a figure and a table next to one another in the IEEEtrans document class (2 columns). Each should have its own caption, so subfloat can't be used and, the table needs to have its specific IEEE caption style.

Thank you for your help!

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Are you sure it will fit in a single column? Or you want it to span two columns? In that case https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/271347/minipage-across-two-columns is related, maybe even a duplicate.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply!
It should be in a single column. It is mainly the captions that are the issue as the caption length should be limited to a fraction of the columnwidth and should be in the specific IEEE style.

Comment: image and table include into the same float. `table`, for figure caption use `capt-of` package: `\captionof{figure}{ figure caption}`.  Of course youre image as wel table should be small enough.

Answer (score 1):

You can use two minipages of 0.45 columnwidth side by side.

Because inside a minipage floating environments (such as `table` or `figure`) are not allowed, the `tabular` and `includegraphics` commands should be used without the surrounding environments.

To indicate which type of float it is and to provide captions and labels, you can use `\captionof` from the `capt-of` package (note that the `caption` package also provides `captionof`, but that package is incompatible with `IEEEtran`).

Finally, you can put both minipages together in a float without a caption (for example a `figure`), to float to the top and provide some vertical space as specified by the IEEE style.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{capt-of}
\begin{document}
\setcounter{table}{1}
\setcounter{figure}{1}
See Figure \ref{fig:redundant} and Table \ref{tab:states}.
\lipsum[1]
\begin{figure}
\begin{minipage}{0.45\columnwidth}
\centering\fbox{this is a figure}
\captionof{figure}{Redundant system $s_t$ with a redundant caption that spans multiple lines}
\label{fig:redundant}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}{0.45\columnwidth}
\centering\fbox{this is a table}
\captionof{table}{Redundancy states of $o_2 \in \mathcal{O}^{\psi_1}_{\phi_1}$}
\label{tab:states}
\end{minipage}
\end{figure}
\lipsum[1-10]
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Works like a charm!!! Thanks a lot!

Comment: when I try this, the text in the tabular environment shows up larger than the default article text. How can this be fixed?

Comment: @DanielV that could be caused by many things. You could try putting `\small` at the start of the minipage, or one of the other size commands. If that doesn't work then it is best to ask a new question with a small example document that reproduces your issue.